# Can a Windows 10 user be configured to use only a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

My home PC is running Windows 10 with two users: one for myself and one for my son.  My son is soon to turn 13 and I would like to give him a bit more responsibility with regard to his computer use.  E.g. access to his own emails, social media etc.  In order to reduce the risks to my machine, I would like to configure his user account so that it runs in a virtual machine from the moment he logs in.  Is this possible and, if so, how?

Can I configure a Windows 10 user account to run entirely and automatically in a virtual machine from log on to log off?

Comment: Windows isn't designed this way. Give him a normal account. He can only stuff his own account, not yours, not the computers. Trust Microsoft to know what they are doing after 30 years.

Comment: What you want pretty much would require a separate machine. So if you want to go ahead with that getting some additional hardware might be a good option. There are solutions which will allow for temporary changes only (usually used e.g. in schools). Another option might to use a removeable HDD enclosure and frequently change between entire drives. Using a regular user account for your son is probably going to be easier and cheaper.

Comment: As @Mark pointed out, give him his own account as limited user, and optionally you can install a VM for him that he can start where he can do everything. You just have to teach him how to operate the VM.

Comment: Either use a limited account, get a small device or smart phone with email, or watch with the child as they are using the computer. That works for us

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it by myself, but windows 10 Pro (and Enterprise) supports a built-in VM Sandbox. See here, different resources with setup and config infos:

1) https://www.howtogeek.com/399153/windows-10s-new-sandbox-feature-is-everything-weve-always-wanted/

2) https://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-windows-sandbox-windows-10

3) https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/143381-windows-sandbox-how-configure-windows-10-a.html

Next would be an autostart entry that will launch this Sandbox for the user-account of your son. As this sandbox creates a shortcut in the start menu, you maybe can grab the launcher there and put it in the startup folder of your son's profile:

`C:\Users\ <usermane> \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

A true "he can't make something bad" solution isn't possible on the same machine, but maybe you have the Pro version of Win 10 and this is helpful enough?

Comment: This is not a good solution because it does not give his son a place where he can fool around endlessly. The sandbox will reset after every shutdown, which will discourage any experimentation. As child, you want to try something and a month or so later, continue based on a previous experiment. If your changes are gone, you will learn that nothing is permanent and stop testing.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, although as pointed out by @LPChip any changes will not be persistent between sessions.  I would like for him to be able to download games and apps, but have a non-destructive recovery mechanism in the event that they include some form of ransomware or keylogger, etc.

Comment: Well, basically every other VM will do the same - with the difference, that other VMs might be configured to store changes. Just an idea, not sure how this will work out for you and your son :) Also: If he will be able to download Apps and so on, he will be able to destroy something. How non-destructive a VM solution would be depends on the methods and intervals of creating a backup. The more frequent a VM is saved in a working state, the better in the worst case.